# How to program securely when you can only expect advisory file locks where the program will be used?

Tags: c++, c

Asked on the grounds of: "...but if your question generally covers…
- a specific programming problem..." (Help center - asking)

Scope: This is not about how to use the file lock mechanisms on different platforms, but about how to mitigate the absence of mandatory file locks on the user's system. E.g.: I can't expect a user of a Linux system to modify the system, let alone *know* how to do it, so I have to assume advisory locks is all that is available. I have found a lot of info about how to use locks of both kinds, and what is available on some platforms, and even why they are not available on some systems. Portability would be great, but this is probably to much down to the bone for that.

I am a bit confused about how to safeguard my program's data if other processes don't cooperate, intentionally or not. Assuming that my program uses its own directory for the data, is there a way to make sure that my data will stay consistent while the program runs?

Would, for example, temporary hidden files be a practical solution (create a file, delete it from the OS' directory, so only my handle holds the inode to the file), copying all data at program start and overwriting the original at the end? It seems to be *very* platform specific, though.

Are there specific mechanisms or techniques to use that could help with this, or can I only "trust"?

Note: This is not specifically about Linux, it's just an example.

------ EDIT -------

I'm looking for a way to do this that works in C/C++, hence those tags, but am aware that it might involve system specific features. If possible, the solution would work regardless of platform and file locking mechanism.

While file locks is the mechanism referenced in the question, the real problem is how to prevent another process from trampling over the data my program relies on *while running*, even if that process runs as the same user as my program does, but does not care to check whether the files are locked. Also if it is using a mechanism that isn't working well with the one my program is using. (AFAICT, locks acquired  with one of flock()/lockf() on Linux may not work when the other is used in the other process) (Another situation from Linux, but one that is outside the scope of the question)

As I tried to explain about the scope, this is not about how to use file locks on any platform, but what to do when you cannot assume anything about what mechanism is available/turned on, to achieve similar protection to what mandatory file locks would give.

Comment: How is this a question about c or c++??? Also if its not Linux then you specifically target linux?? For that system I would say file permissions is the way to go. Most OSes have something similar. Any reason you can't rely on the permissions system of the OS. Is this question about file locks?? E.g. in Linux you don't have mandatory locks. Of course you need permission to modify data, so again we go back to file permissions. So.. i don't get the focus of this question i guess

Comment: You could code another server process which implements some abstract locking. Or use a database for that.

Comment: @Brandin I see I wasn't clear about those things. Sorry. I'll try to edit the question.

Comment: You should identify the scope of your cross-platform-ness.  If it is variants of Linux, you may get one answer; if you have to include Mac OS X and BSD too, you may get another; if you need to include HP-UX, Solaris, AIX (SCO, ...), you get yet another answer; if you need to include Windows too, you get yet another answer; and if you need to cover Android, iOS and Windows Phone too, you probably get still more answers.  The extent of your portability requirements does affect the answers you might receive.

Comment: @Jonathan What brought this up was seeing the difference in how Unix/Linux and Windows handles file locks. In searching for how to deal with this, I couldn't find any solutions. I'm beginning to wonder if I just missed the real answer, that this _shouldn't_ be the responsibility of the program, but of the _system_, as suggested in the answer from David Schwartz below. But I am still not sure of whether I _should_ deal with this, or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a bit confused about how to safeguard my program's data if other processes don't cooperate, intentionally or not. Assuming that my program uses its own directory for the data, is there a way to make sure that my data will stay consistent while the program runs?

You cannot do so and should not even try to do so. How do you safeguard your data if the admin pulls the power cord? All things with access to your data *must* cooperate -- that is the precondition for safeguarding being possible.

Simply specify that your program requires a directory that is only touched by programs that cooperate with yours. That is a trivial requirement that many programs have any any competent administrator can provide.

Comment: So what you're saying is that any protection is in whatever measures the administrator puts around the system, and if any misbehaving program is let in, lets hope there is a recent backup? And that _that_ is the reason why mandatory/advisory locking doesn't' matter?

Comment: That's pretty much it.

Comment: Yes. It almost never makes sense to code defensively against someone tampering with your data behind your back and in violation of your access rules. At most, you might try to detect such subterfuge where possible and terminate with a sane error. But it's a fools errand to try to operate robustly in environments so broken sane operation isn't possible.

Comment: Personally I hate mandatory locks when im admining the system. If you're root you should have access to the file, period. To a large degree, if you mess up the system as the sysadmin then this is your problem as the sysadmin